# Why can't my Galaxy S7 send and receive messages simultaneously?

Tags: sms, samsung-galaxy-s7

So I've had my S7 for several months now, and by and far the most annoying thing is that it can't seem to send a message while simultaneously receiving a message. Way too often I'll be texting back and forth with a friend, and I'll hit send at the same time my phone receives a new text message. This causes my message to "spin" (the circle next to it spins) for about thirty seconds, before the notification about the message failing to send appears. It's super annoying, because I'll usually copy & paste the text and send a new message before the failed message notification even appears, because the new one will send instantly, while the other still is spinning!

Is this a common issue for the S7? I don't recall it happening with my Galaxy S4. Or is this expected behavior for the messaging app?

Comment: It's also possible that it's a network issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is not your mobile phone's problem, but it is the issue with service provider, which don't allow this to be done. There is a point where it gives a few seconds to check if there are any stuck messages. It may also be the messaging app your using which might have a bug. During call, do you receive messages ?